# Restoring a postgresql from a dump if a login with the same name doesn't exist

Tags: linux, postgresql, arch-linux

On a serverA I have a postgresql database with a user user_a. I've made a dump of it:

```
pg_dump postgres > db1.bak
```

On a serverB I have a database with a user user_b. I've tried to restore a database from the dump made on the serverA and it failed:

```
  psql my_db < db1.bak 
  psql: FATAL:  role "user_b" does not exist
```

Do I really have to create user_a on the serverB? I want to avoid that because on a serverB I want to have only user_b.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a common username for the backup role.

Imagine if someday you got serverC...

Answer (score 1):

You can create user_a just for importing, do the import, change the owner of the imported database to user_b then drop user_a.